# Send string from an activity B to a fragment F of activity A

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two activities (A & B) and my fragment F is contained in the activity A. I'd like to send strings from activity B to fragment F. How can I do that? Here's my code:

**ACTIVITY B**

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.sample.MESSAGE";

// onClick get button from activity B layout
public void get(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
    String message = textView.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**FRAGMENT F**

```
EditText editText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String num = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    // EditText from fragment F layout
    editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_coordinates);    
    editText.setText(num);
    return v;
}
```

I don't get any errors when i run it on my device but I'm not getting the strings to my EditText

Comment: nice use of constants

Comment: Send like B-->A then A-->Fragment F

Comment: you sent EXTRA_MESSAGE as a variable and get it as a string. their value is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `"EXTRA_MESSAGE"` with `"com.sample.MESSAGE"` in fragment

so Replace

```
 String num = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");// OR Double quotes
```

with

```
String num = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("com.sample.MESSAGE");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the correct value.

```
    String num = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("com.sample.MESSAGE");
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to retrieve the String passed using the constant name as literal instead the constant content you should try:

```
String num = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(ActivityB.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

or:

```
String num = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("com.sample.MESSAGE");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you wanna pass the string, either coupled way or decoupled way.

You can use the default static instance of Fragment then pass in a bundle with the string as argument.

You can probably initialize a non-default constructor for a Fragment with a string as an argument, though not recommended.

Or if you wanna do it the decoupled way, you can probably use Greenrobot's Eventbus to pass your string from the activity to the fragment. Go look up the documentation and see if it fits your purpose or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
String num = getArguments().getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

Comment: I think it rather: getArguments().getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
(cf. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#getString(java.lang.String) )